# C++ std::stack Traversal

Tags: c++, stack, std

I am using `std::stack` for an project and I need to travel on it for checking same values. I checked member functions but, I could not find an appropriate one for this task.

The first idea that came up is using a copy stack but, the program might waste lots of extra space in this case, and not using an user-defined stack class is important at this level of the project (Yeah, I made a design mistake... ).

So, any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: A stack is the wrong data structure. Does the ordering of the items on the stack matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid `std::stack`, it's just a useless wrapper that dumbs down the interface of the underlying container. Use a `std::vector` with `push_back`/`pop_back` for insert insertion/removal (insertion/removal at the end is amortized O(1)) or `std::deque`, whence you can push/pop on either side without significant changes in performances (still amortized O(1)). In both cases you can walk all the elements using their random-access iterators.

(the same holds for `std::queue`: it's useless, use directly `std::deque` (*not* vector) with `push_back`/`pop_front`)

Comment: I did not know that vector has these kinds of methods. Thank you, again.

Comment: A `std::stack` is not useless. Yes, its functionality is much reduced compared to its underlying container, but that's also its strength: it's *only* a stack and if that's all one needs, then this makes the program clearer and easier to maintain than using, say, a `std::deque`.

Comment: @Walter: please provide one case where it actually made the program "cleaner and easier to maintain"; in my experience it only made me waste a lot of time renaming `pop` to `pop_back`, `push` to `push_back` and `top` to `back` whenever I needed to access the underlying container for any reason (for oh-so-rare scenarios like iterating over the elements after the first part of an algorithm accumulated them on the stack; printing the stack content for logging/debugging purposes; passing the full stack to any other function to process the elements; peeking at more than one element on the top).

Comment: @MatteoItalia If you want more than a stack (i.e. iterators etc), don't use a stack. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Is a car useless because you cannot haul boxes bigger than fit in the trunk? I could buy a truck but then I'm driving around in a truck all day just in case I need it's truck functionality one day in the far future. Yeah, a car is useless if you need to haul a ton of goods. So always buy a truck? That seems like bad advice.

Comment: @DavidRector: there's no car here, there is just a nice regular truck with the loading bay welded to let you load only tiny packets.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: I don't know, if the class is lighter weight, I would think of it as a car, not a truck. I get the point but I don't think a limited class is useless unless you have a use that goes beyond what it supplies. Otherwise, I could say that a deque is useless because it doesn't have the features of a KD-tree. Well, that's only true if I need a KD-tree and not a deque. "Useless" is just a bit extreme. "Limited" would be a better description of the stack class (which I never use because it is too limited).

Comment: @DavidRector: the class isn't more lightweight or anything, as under it there's `std::vector` or `std::deque` or whatever you pass to it as template parameter, it just restricts the interface of the underlying container. The analogy with `deque` being useless because it isn't a KD-tree doesn't hold - a `deque` is a different data structure than a KD-tree, an `std::stack` is *literally*  an `std::vector` locked down to a dumb interface.